# Unbound variable during associative array initialization and access

Tags: bash

With enabled unbound variables check (`set -u`), bash fails to initialize and access associative array:

during initialization

```
set -u
declare -a qwe=()
qwe[asd]=val # bash: asd: unbound variable
```

during access:

```
declare -a qwe=()
qwe[asd]=val
set -u
echo ${qwe[asd]} # bash: asd: unbound variable
```

Bash version: `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Am I missing something or it is some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`qwe` is an array, with integer indexing. When you write `qwe[asd]`, Bash knows that `asd` has to be an integer, so it tries to get the value of a variable `$asd` (it handles the content of the square brackets as an "arithmetic context"); if it is unset, it would default to `0`, but because of `set -u`, you get an error instead.

Did you mean `declare -A` for an associative array?